# Convert Datetime/Date to NVarchar Format in SQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, date, datetime, nvarchar

I created several tables and the format is in datetime or date. However i need to change them into nvarchar. The way I see it is I need to to drop all the tables, modify the data type and re-create it all.
Is there a way where i can automatically change the data type?

Comment: Why? Do you not want to store dates anymore? If the column contains dates, keep the date datatype. If the column stores anything other than dates, is your model correct?

Comment: Terrible, terrible idea and is against all logic. Keep them as DATETIME and use a format or convert function to display it however you want. Changing the data type to varchar would force you to convert it back to DATETIME every time you needed to do any ORDER BY or DATE or TIME functions. Save yourself the headache

Answer (score 0):

In place of getdate please place your column and try

```
   SELECT CONVERT(nvarchar(10), getdate(), 103)
```

Answer (score 0):

If the columns were accidentally set to be `DATETIME` columns and you want to change their type, that's no problem:

```
ALTER TABLE myTable ALTER COLUMN myColumn NVARCHAR(55);
```

But as others have said, if the tables already have data and if these columns are intended to actually save `DATE` values, then you should seriously reconsider doing this.